# glVertex3f take array as an argument?

Tags: c++, opengl, heightmap

I'm trying to implement a heightmap to my code, but the array I'm using seems to be wrong and the opengl vertex function cannot recognize it, can some one help me with it?

```
float* Createheightmap(int sizex, int sizez) {
float map[][] = new float[sizex][sizez];
for (int i = 0; i < sizex; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizez; j++) {
        map[i][j] = float(0.0);
    }
}
return map;

}

void drawterrian(void) {
    float* map=Createheightmap(sizex,sizez);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizex; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizez; j++) {
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glVertex3f(float(i),map[i][j],float(j));
                glVertex3f(float(i+1),map[i+1][j],float(j));
                glVertex3f(float(i+1),map[i+1][j+1],float(j+1));
                glVertex3f(float(i),map[i][j+1],float(j+1));

            glEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

The size of the array is declared in earlier functions

Comment: *but the array I'm using seems to be wrong and the opengl vertex function cannot recognize it* What do you mean by that exactly? (P.S: unrelated but youre leaking that float array, consider using smart ptrs or containers)

Comment: it was showed "invalid arguments' "in eclipse

Comment: What do you mean by "leaking the float array"?

Comment: 1) Invalid arguments: you have a 1D ptr and youre "indexing" it twice, that wont work, 2) you newed the array, but never delete it, so your leaking memory.

Comment: so I type another "*"after the float* it there is now error now, Should it be good now?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [similar problem](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/137690-GL_POLYGON-and-colors) to yours.  Are you assigning a normal to the polygon with [glNormal](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glNormal.xml) anywhere?

Another thing that will be an issue is that you are exceeding the bounds of your array `map` with the `i+1` and `j+1` indices in `drawterrian`.  Modify the bounds on your `for` loops to make sure this doesn't happen.

As mentioned in the comments, be careful when creating variables with `new`.  Make sure to `delete` them afterwards.  You may need to adjust your `Createheightmap` function in a different way to do this.